# How to resolve Error: Cannot find module 'xmlhttprequest' during loading of "browser-sync.js" tasks

Tags: jhipster

I got the error below when upgrading to jHipster v2.20.0 and also when running a grunt build:

```
bootstrap#3.3.5 src\main\webapp\bower_components\bootstrap

└── jquery#2.1.4

Loading "browser-sync.js" tasks...ERROR
**>> Error: Cannot find module 'xmlhttprequest'**
```

I had the same issue in prior version of jHipster so I doubt its related to v2.20.0 specifically.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something went wrong during `npm install` after you upgraded JHipster.
Please try to run it again in your project folder.

If it does not work you could try `npm install xmlhttprequest`

Comment: Thanks Gael, the npm install works like a charm on my Mac on Java 8 but doesn't resolve the issue from one of my windows development slices on Java 7.  Any thoughts on why windows would fail?  It used to work for me just fine a couple months back.

Comment: Windows is not he best platform for nodeJS, try 'npm cache clean', delete your project's node_modules and run again 'npm install'. if this does not work, re-install node and ideally using a manager like nodist.